# Blank permission screen on login attempt

Tags: android, permissions, facebook

I'm making an android app that allows users to login with their facebook accounts.  I can run it on the emulator and log in and out of my account perfectly.  However, when i then tried to do the same on my actual android, when i went to login a blank facebook dialog poped up with the title "Permissions".  There's a "Okay" button at the top right of the dialog, and when i click that it gives me the following error:

An error occurred with [App Name].  Please try again later.
API Error Code: 100
APE Error Description: Invalid Parameter
Error Message: Requires valid redirect URI.

My phone automatically logs me in because i have the facebook app installed on  it but not the emulator, whereas my emulator i have to enter my info every time.

This only happens when i try to use the same account for both my phone and the emulator.  With different accounts for each everything works fine

Answer (score 2):

Mate,

I've been fighting with this issue for a couple of days, and almost throw away my project.

The problem resides in the following setting:

App settings-> Advanced Settings -> Enhanced Auth Dialog: true

If you set that value to false, it will run like a charm. It seems that the facebook guys are testing non-working stuff with us, without a warning! The default value is true, set it to false and problem solved!

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I can't seem to find the settings you're talking about though.  Where exactly is app settings?

Comment: Goto your https://developers.facebook.com/apps select your app, and click on "edit settings", then Appsettings->advanced settings->Enhanced auth dialog...